# How to describe the condition of not having enough light in the room?

Tags: word-request

I work in a room where it does not have enough light but it is not a dimmed room. If regular office rooms get 10 score on the brightness of light, this room would get 6. The lighting condition is like one in the picture below.

[image: a dimmed room?]

Is there an English work to describe such a condition?

Comment: Insufficiently/Inadequately illuminated office. Subdued/dim lighting.

Comment: Poor lighting, or "It's too dark in here!"

Comment: The room may be *dim*, but it is not *dark*. One could say the lighting is *subdued*, but this is not all that idiomatic. But I don't a native speaker who who would say that this room is *dark*.

Comment: Insufficent lighting

Comment: I would say it's too dark. The room may not be dark compared to other rooms, but it is too dark for me to work in. It doesn't have enough ambient light to prevent eye strain.

Answer (score 3):

[Peter's answer](/a/80344/10820) gets part of the way there: "too X to Y", if X is the opposite of Z, is a useful construction in general to say that there's some Z lacking that makes it hard to do Y, even if there's still a pretty significant amount of Z. That is, even if the room isn't very dark, it can still be "too dark to work" or "too dark to read".

However, in this case, "too dim to work" is probably better. That's a somewhat weaker opposition, and in cases where there's really not much lacking at all, that has a better match to the idea that a smaller change might fix it.

Alternatively, say "not bright enough in here to work". Similarly, you can use "There's not enough light in here to work." In this case, rather than negating the basic adjective ("light" → "dark") you're negating the adjectival phrase ("enough light" → "not enough light").

Answer (score 2):

Not having enough lighting can be expressed by simply saying

> **It's too dark to work in here.**

and that will cover cases of **diminished** lighting to **no lighting**.

In an **office** environment, this situation can be described as

> **poor lighting**
>   **inadequate lighting**
>   **insufficient lighting**
>   **dim lighting**  *(different from* ***dimmed*** *lighting)*
>   **lowered lighting**

In a **home** when done for effect, it can be called

> **mood lighting**
>   **subtle lighting**
>   **romantic lighting**
>   **tv lighting**

Comment: I downvoted this answer because I do not know a single native speaker who would describe this room as being *dark*.

Comment: @GoDucks well. Isn't it kinda dark, though?

Comment: @NVZ It might be kinda dark for some activities and kinda bright for others. But, as a general term, the room is not dark.

Comment: The answer is not referencing the room in the picture, it is a general statement when entering **a room which does not have enough light**. We actually don't know how bright/dark the room in the picture actually is since we don't know the camera settings. The dynamic range is fairly flat which would indicate it's not favorably lit

Comment: Edited to state, "It's too dark to work in here." Any objections to this change?

Comment: I am a native AE speaker.  I like dimly lit rooms, especially at night, while my husband does NOT.  I hear "It's too dark in here!",  referring to the room, all the time.  As an aside, a "dark room" refers to a room that is used to develop silver-based film.  A room can be described as  gloomy or darkened...

Comment: A dark room describes a room which is dark. A *darkroom* is a room for old-school film development.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an English work to describe such a condition?

There isn't a single word, unfortunately.

When something blocks light, the effect is called *shade*, but that implies being outside.

During the day, it is reasonable to leave the lights out and expect the natural sunlight to fill the room.  The first thing that comes to mind is *this room doesn't have enough natural light.*  Because typically you could turn on a light to illuminate the room but just would prefer not because of the available sunlight.

Answer (score 2):

You could say the room is ***[underlit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underlit)***.

*Lit* can be used as an adjective meaning "supplied with light" (as in *the great hall was lit by candles and torches*), and the prefix *under-* indicates that something is not enough (as in *undersized*, *underfunded*, *underachiever*).

If the room had too much light, you could say it was ***overlit***.

I believe these words are often used by photographers to describe a scene that has too little or too much light for a satisfactory photograph.